# Extenstion of Caputo's fractional derivative to distribution.

Tags: real-analysis, calculus, derivatives, fractional-calculus

Let us start with the definitions that
$\frac{d}{dx}\theta(x)=\delta(x)$ where $\theta(x)$ and $\delta(x)$ are Heaviside and delta functions.

Now, with the definition:
$^c D^\alpha f(t)=\frac{1}{\Gamma(n-\alpha)}\int_0^t\frac{\frac{d^n}{dx^n}f(x)}{(t-x)^{\alpha-n+1}}\mathrm d x$
I want to understand what is the half-derivative of the $\theta(x)$ such that applying another half derivative on the result gives the delta function.

For a simple function like say $f(t)=sin(x)$ one can look at the Taylor expansion and for each power of x, the formula gives the half derivative to be
$$^c D^\frac12 x^p=\frac{p x^{p-\frac{1}{2}} \Gamma (p)}{\Gamma \left(p+\frac{1}{2}\right)}$$

such that application of another half derivative gives the same result as the full derivative *i.e.* $px^{p-1}$. However, for the Heaviside theta function, the first application gives
$$^c D^\frac12 \theta(x)=\frac{2 \theta (x)-1}{\sqrt{\pi } \sqrt{x}}$$

and now I am usure how to show that the second application gives the Delta function.

Answer (score 2):

Too long for a comment:

The derivative of a distribution $\theta$ is defined as
$$
( \partial_x \theta, \varphi):= -(\theta, \partial_x \varphi)
$$
For any function $\varphi \in C^\infty_c$ (or if the distribution has compact support $C^\infty$)

As such the most natural definition for the fractional derivative of a distribution will be

$$
( ^cD^{\frac{1}{2}} \theta, \varphi):=i(\theta,   ^cD^{\frac{1}{2}} \varphi)
$$
for any smooth (with compact support) $\varphi$.

It is immediate to see that $\left( ^cD^{\frac{1}{2}}\right)^2\theta=\partial_x\theta$ for any distribution $\theta$

I would be surprised if the fractional derivative of the heaviside function is a function and not a distribution as it would be

$$
(^cD^{\frac{1}{2}} \theta, \varphi)= \frac{i}{\Gamma(n-\frac{1}{2})} \int_{\mathbb{R}} \theta(t) \int_0^t\dfrac{\partial_x^n \varphi(x)}{(t-x)^{a-n-1}} dx dt=
$$

$$=\frac{i}{\Gamma(n-\frac{1}{2})}\int_0^\infty \int_{0}^t   \dfrac{\partial_x^n \varphi(x)}{(t-x)^{a-n-1}} dx dt
$$
That does not look as it can be written as a function